# Optimal P Trap height

Tags: bathroom-fixtures

I am removing a piece of galvanized drain while in the process of replacing the vanity.The galvanized is connected to the abs drain pipe entering the waste stack by a rubber connector. In order to reach the clamp screws, I’ve had to remove drywall from a basement wall, but at least I can now reach it. 
Because the new vanity is taller, and since I’m removing the length of Galvanized pipe in the wall, I’m wondering if I should raise the ptrap. Other posts have made it sound arbitrary depending on the fixture height.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot just arbitrarily raise a trap to whatever height you want, it depends on the configuration of the venting system.

For example, if your lav sink drains into a horizontal wet vent type the trap weir must be below the vent connection height.

Answer (score 0):

raising the trap will give you more cupboard space, so if it's not too much effort it's a good idea.